# Issue implementing setBackground of a button within a switch

Tags: android

I'm creating an app that requires the background image of a button to change once pressed. At this time the Click detection is done in a switch, with the pressed button changing to the ic_launcher for now.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.r1c1:
            r1c1.setBackground(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            break;
       case R.id.r2c1:
            r2c1.setBackground(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            break;
       default:
            throw new RuntimeException("Unknow button ID");
    }
}
```

I'm using multiple LinearLayouts to create rows of buttons, the XML of which is thus

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- Row 1 -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/row1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/r1c1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />

</LinearLayout> <!-- End Row 1 -->

<!-- Row 2 -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/row2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/r2c1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />

</LinearLayout><!-- End Row 2 -->
```

The error I'm receiving is i.e. 'r1c1 cannot be resolved'. My guess is I'm just not referencing this correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setBackground method can only be accessed through a View object.

I recommend you do the following:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.r1c1:
            v.setBackground(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            break;
       case R.id.r2c1:
            v.setBackground(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            break;
       default:
            throw new RuntimeException("Unknow button ID");
    }
}
```

This works because every Button object has a base class of View.
By using a switch statement as you did above, you know which Button the `View v` belongs to.

So the `View v`, is actually referring to the view of the Button you are trying to modify.

Comment: Yes thank you! Sorry for the delay, haven't had a chance to get back to this.